# Unix - print distinct field lengths

Tags: unix, if-statement, awk, printing

I would like to print the total number of times each length occurs in a field.

The column type is varChar and the strings in that field are either 9, 10, or 15 characters long.  I want to know how many exist of each length.

My code:

```
awk -F'|' 
'NR>1 $61!="" && 
if /length($61)=15/ then {a++} 
elif /length($61)=10/ then {b++} 
else /length($61)=9/ then {c++} 
fi {print a ", " b ", " c}'
```

ERROR:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1 $61!="" && if /length($61)=15/ then {a++} elif /length($61)=10/ then {b++} else /length($61)=9/ then {c++} fi {print a ", " b ", " c}' 
 Syntax Error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                NR>1 >>>  $61!= <<<
 awk: 0602-500 Quitting The source line is 1.
```

INPUT

A pipe delimited .sqf file with 1.2 million rows and column 61 is varChar 15.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: All is told to you : The error context is
                NR>1 >>>  $61!= <<<

Comment: yeah but once she fixes that syntax error then she'll hit the next syntax error and then the one after that and then the one after that... It's time for the OP to do a bit of research  on awk syntax and start over!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your pseudo-code I guess you want

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS=', ' 'NR>1 {count[length($61)]++}
                       END  {print count[15],count[10],count[9]}' file
```

you'll also have the other length counts there in case of data quality check.

If you want to have 0 instead of null for missing counts, change to `count[n]+0` as suggested in the comments.